# decoded = visually encoded

Tags: cryptography, base64, decode, encode

Is it possible to decode base64 to image(or string) contains visually same base64, or reverse, so it's loops to recursion.

[image]

P.S. base64 actually it's not the goal, so if you know other funny ways with decoded = visually encoded, I will be very appreciate.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please explain it once again for me..?

Comment: Fox example: open MS Paint and write some random base64 in it with text tool, save as .jpg
Next, encode this .jpg to base64 and you will get another base64 string, but different from random base64 drawed on .jpg.

I need that base64 on picture will equal to base64 I get after encoding this picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't found solution, but compromise for my needs:
First: image to base64; Second: image to color ascII-art contain prev base64 string.

Test example:
[image]

P.S. Of course it's fake, but it works exactly as close as I wanted, I think on some sort of simple images it can works very usefull.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to decode base64 to image(or string) contains visually same base64, or reverse, so it's loops to recursion.

So you want a base64-encoding-quine (see [quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29)).  Restated, you'd like either:

1. An `x` such that `ascii(decode_base64(x)) == x`.  This isn't possible because base64 is strictly larger than the value being encoded.  So the result of decoding yields something smaller than the initial value.
2. An `x` such that `some_really_vague_image_decoding(decode_base64(x)) ~ x`.  This probably isn't possible for any standard image encoding because the number of bits required to represent a pixel, and number of pixels required to represent a character, are far larger than the 6 bits provided by a single base64 character.